# Extracting the number of value occurrences from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, counter

I am trying to extract a sum of values from a nested dictionary and preserve the key name as a new dictionary.

I have been attempting various methods from researching here but below is the closest I have gotten.

Source dictionary:

```
result_data=

{
   "uhawjjh4": {
     "GET": "GREEN",
     "POST": "GREEN",
     "Query": "GREEN",
     "Cookie": "RED",
     "String": "RED",
     "Body": "BLUE"
   },
   "bcfp19sg": {
     "GET": "GREEN",
     "POST": "GREEN",
     "Query": "RED",
     "Cookie": "RED",
     "String": "RED",
     "Body": "BLUE"
   }
 }
```

Code:

```
    result_data_global = Counter()
    for data in result_data.values():
        result_data_global += Counter(data.keys())
```

Result:

```
  {
    "GREEN": 5,
    "RED": 5,
    "BLUE": 2,
  }
```

What I need is the key and value with the totals:

```
{
      "GET": {"GREEN": 2},
      "POST": {"GREEN": 2},
      "Query": {"GREEN": 1, “RED”: 1},
       ....
{
```

Probably simple but not having success here. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have two `"Query"` keys? Do you mean to have it as `"Query": {"GREEN": 1, "RED": 1}`?

Comment: @Tomothy32 No, each top level uuid is a different record / result set.

Comment: By nature of the implementation, dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict.setdefault`:

```
result = {}
for d in result_data.values():
    for k, v in d.items():
        result[k][v] = result.setdefault(k, {}).get(v, 0) + 1
```

`result` becomes:

```
{'GET': {'GREEN': 2}, 'POST': {'GREEN': 2}, 'Query': {'GREEN': 1, 'RED': 1}, 'Cookie': {'RED': 2}, 'String': {'RED': 2}, 'Body': {'BLUE': 2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
d = {'uhawjjh4': {'GET': 'GREEN', 'POST': 'GREEN', 'Query': 'GREEN', 'Cookie': 'RED', 'String': 'RED', 'Body': 'BLUE'}, 'bcfp19sg': {'GET': 'GREEN', 'POST': 'GREEN', 'Query': 'RED', 'Cookie': 'RED', 'String': 'RED', 'Body': 'BLUE'}}
new_d = defaultdict(list)
result = [i for b in d.values() for i in b.items()]
for a, b in result:
  new_d[a].append(b)

new_result = {a:dict(Counter(b)) for a, b in new_d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'GET': {'GREEN': 2}, 'POST': {'GREEN': 2}, 'Query': {'GREEN': 1, 'RED': 1}, 'Cookie': {'RED': 2}, 'String': {'RED': 2}, 'Body': {'BLUE': 2}}
```